# Нужна ли запятая с повтором "тут"?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, уточнения

Форумчане, развейте сомнения. В тексте написано "тут-тут. Без сознания, ага..." Мне кажется, что в случае "тут-тут" не ставится дефис, нужна запятая. Так ли? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

В подобных случаях возможна двоякая пунктуация. Запятая ставится между повторяющимися словами, произносимыми с интонацией перечисления.

Дефис же употребляется для усиления значения.

Ср.: Далеко-далеко колокольчик звенит (Ник.); Много, много времени прошло с тех пор;
***Розенталь. Д. Э. Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуации***

[§ 16. Запятая при повторяющихся словах](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=105#pp105)  [§ 17. Дефисное написание повторяющихся слов](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106#pp106)

Answer (score 1):

Обычно встречается **написание с запятой:**

― Верно! У него! **Тут, тут**… Стой! Да это червонцы! [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 1 (1929-1940)]

Он показал пальцем на спину и сказал зло: ― **Тут, тут**, вот он. Говорите шепотом, Салерно. [Б. С. Житков. Механик Салерно (1935)]

Иногда "тут" может иметь   **временное значение** (многоточие на письме):

Еще мгновение ― и с их губ слетят слова, **но тут… тут** Таня вдруг услышала чей-то громкий голос. [Дмитрий Емец. Таня Гроттер и магический контрабас (2002)]

Answer (score 0):

> В тексте написано "тут-тут. Без сознания, ага..." Мне кажется, что в
>   случае "тут-тут" не ставится дефис, нужна запятая. Так ли?

Без контекста наверняка сказать трудно, но по первому впечатлению здесь дефисное написание вполне разумно и кабы не единственно возможно.

В целом написания определятся смыслом и отчасти - стилистикой, акцентом...

В первую очередь я бы посмотрел на значение этого "тут" с повтором.
В вашей фразе "тут-тут" выступает скорее всего в роли междометия, на вопрос "где?" совсем не отвечающего, а просто вводящего слушателя в ситуацию. А в таких случаях запятая совершенно не нужна.

Кстати, в других ответах есть примеры другого написания, но там это объясняется именно грамматической ролью "тут" - местоименного наречия.